# position of the window of the menu function

Tags: matlab

I use the `menu()` function. The output window is in the left upper corner of the screen. 
So the question is, is there a possibility to change that position? 
( And of course I know the possibility with the courser )

Answer (score 0):

did you try this? It works for figures for sure, not 100% sure about menus. 
http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html?s_tid=doc_12b